# E-mail e senha no aplicativo Android Studio não cadastra no Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Não aparece nenhum tipo de erro quando eu clico para cadastrar no botão, já coloquei todos os tipos de tamanhos senha e coloquei até meu próprio e-mail válido só que não cadastra na autenticação do firebase.

```
private void Cadastrar() {

    nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_cadastro_nome);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_cadastro_email);
    senha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_cadastro_senha);
    botaoCadastar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_cadastrar);

    botaoCadastar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            usuario = new Usuario();
            usuario.setNome(nome.getText().toString());
            usuario.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
            usuario.setSenha(senha.getText().toString());
            cadastarUsuario();
        }
    });
}

private void cadastarUsuario(){

    autenticacao = ConfiguracaoFireBase.getFirebaseAutenticacao();
    autenticacao.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            usuario.getEmail(),
            usuario.getSenha()
    ).addOnCompleteListener(CadastroUsuarioActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(CadastroUsuarioActivity.this,"Sucesso ao cadastrar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i(usuario.getEmail(), "Erro");
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(CadastroUsuarioActivity.this,"Erro ao cadastrar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

CONFIGURAÇÃO FIREBASE

```
public final class ConfiguracaoFireBase {

    private static DatabaseReference referenciaFirebase;
    private static FirebaseAuth autenticacao;

    public static DatabaseReference getFirebase() {

        if (referenciaFirebase == null) {
            referenciaFirebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        }

        return referenciaFirebase;
    }

    public static FirebaseAuth getFirebaseAutenticacao(){

        if(autenticacao == null){
            autenticacao = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        }
        return autenticacao;
    }
}
```

Comment: O que há nessa classe `ConfiguracaoFireBase`? Onde e como você define a variável `usuario`?

Comment: é onde eu faço a ligação com o firebase

Answer (score 1):

Talvez seu arquivo de regras do firebase esteja restringindo a inserção.

De uma olhada neste [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/?hl=pt-br) e veja se vai te ajudar.

Comment: minhas regras estão corretas

Answer (score 1):

Não vejo nenhum problema no código.

Talvez o que esteja a faltar é habilitar a opção de autenticação por email/password no Firebase.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]